# Receiving Name not defined error and unsure why

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm attempting to add a simple GUI using tkinter to the portscanner code found on the site. The code works fine by itself and the GUI comes up as expected but when the button is clicked to run the function for the portscanner I get this:

```
"btn = Button(root, text='Scan', command= lambda : portscan(port))
NameError: name 'port' is not defined"



def portscan(port):

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(0.5)#

    try:
        con = s.connect((target,port))

        print('Port :',port,"is open.")

        con.close()
    except:
        pass
r = 1
for x in range(1,500):

    t = threading.Thread(target=portscan,kwargs={'port':r})

    r += 1
    t.start()


label = Label(root, text='Target IP: ')
label.place(x=0, y=0)

btn = Button(root, text='Scan', command= lambda : portscan(port))
btn.place(x=100, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `btn = Button(root, text='Scan', command= lambda port: portscan(port))`

Comment: I made that change but I'm now getting the error
     TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional 
     argument:

Comment: how about just `command = portscan`?

Comment: @cibb what line does it say it is at?

Comment: With the `btn = Button(root, text='Scan', command= lambda port: portscan(port))`


I get the error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'port'


the previous error of `name 'port' is not defined` was line 40

Comment: @cibb was the port error fixed, I thought that it was fixed reading your above comments.

Comment: It is resolved. I'm now receiving the error with the added correction of `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'port'`

I'll research that some more in the AM. Thanks for the help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The operator lambda **requires** an argument **before** the colon

"The general syntax of a lambda function is quite simple:

lambda argument_list: expression

The argument list consists of a comma separated list of arguments and the expression is an arithmetic expression using these arguments. You can assign the function to a variable to give it a name.

The following example of a lambda function returns the sum of its two arguments:"

```
sum = lambda x, y : x + y
sum(3,4) #Returns 7
```

or

```
def sum(x,y):
    return x + y
sum(3,4) #Returns 7
```

Sauce: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_lambda.php